# What is the ways to make this loading.tsx show the skeleton?

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

When the page is being loaded for the first time, nothing has been showing, and have to wait for some time to see the main content being loaded.

[image]

The `page.tsx` in the `app` folder has the following HTML.

```js
import { Metadata } from "next"
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator"
import { Sidebar } from '@/components/sidebar'
import FeaturedArticlesContainer from "@/components/FeaturedArticle/featured-article-container"

import { getFeaturedArticles, FeaturedArticle } from '@/data/featureArticle'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import LoadingFeatureArticle from "../components/FeaturedArticle/loading-feature-article"

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Dashboard",
  description: "Example dashboard app built using the components.",
}

export default function DashboardPage() {

  const [featuredArticles, setFeaturedArticles] = useState<FeaturedArticle[]>([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        // Fetch blog list
        const blogListData = await getBlogList();
        setBlogData(blogListData);

        isLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data', error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="md:block">
        <div className="border-t">
          <div className="bg-background">
            <div className="grid lg:grid-cols-5">
              <Sidebar className="hidden lg:block" />
              <div className="col-span-3 lg:col-span-4 lg:border-l">
                <div className="h-full px-4 py-6 lg:px-8">
                  <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                    <div className="space-y-1">
                      <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold tracking-tight">
                        Featured Meditation
                      </h2>
                      <p className="text-sm text-muted-foreground">
                        Top Meditations for you. Updated daily.
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <Separator className="my-4" />
                  <FeaturedArticlesContainer articles={featuredArticles} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

To show the data has been loading with skeleton I have added the `loading.tsx` in the `app` folder, with the following config.

```js
import { Sidebar } from '@/components/sidebar'
import { Separator } from '@/components/ui/separator'
import { Skeleton } from '@/components/ui/skeleton'
import React from 'react'

export default function Loading() {
    return (
        <main>
            <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center">
                <div className="lg:w-3/5 lg:mr-4 mb-4 lg:mb-0 max-w-full lg:max-w-[400px]">
                    <Skeleton className="object-center object-cover transition-all hover:scale-105 lg:w-full max-w-full mb-4 lg:mb-0 h-[250px] w-[600px]" />
                </div>

                <div className="w-full lg:w-2/5 space-y-4 lg:ml-4"> {/* Added left margin for lg */}
                    <Skeleton className="text-xl font-medium leading-normal font-bold h-4 w-full" />
                    <Skeleton className="text-gray-500 h-4 w-full" />
                    <Skeleton className="text-gray-500 h-4 w-full" />
                    <Skeleton className="text-gray-500 h-4 w-full" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}
```

But the loading skeleton is never shown, The data are loaded after some time and the data gets displayed but the loading skeleton doesn't appear.

If I put some conditional logic loaded the `<Loading/>` with the if condition then only the loading skeleton is visible.

What are the ways to make this `loading.tsx` show the skeleton on the page.tsx page?